# How can I filter a list of objects using lambda expression?

Tags: linq, lambda

I know I shouldn't have id's with the same value. This is just fictitious, so overlook that.

I have:

```
List<Car> carList = new List<Car>();
carList.Add(new Car() { id = 1, name = "Honda" });
carList.Add(new Car() { id = 2, name = "Toyota" });
carList.Add(new Car() { id = 1, name = "Nissan" });
```

I want to use Lambda Expression to retrieve all cars that have an id of 1.

Anticipated Result:

```
-- Id: 1, Name: Honda
-- Id: 1, Name: Nissan
```

The problem is more filtering an object list based on a foreign key.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<Car> matchingCars = carList.Where(car => car.id == 1);
```

Using `List<T>.FindAll`:

```
List<Car> matchingCars = carList.FindAll(car => car.id == 1);
```

I would prefer the LINQ approach personally - note that that is lazy, whereas `FindAll` immediately looks through the whole list and builds a new list with the results.

Comment: I don't agree with the LINQ preference, you first need to know the context of the code before you can decide wether to go lazy initialized or not ....

Comment: @Tim: I would usually use LINQ with a `ToList` call afterwards if I wanted eager evaluation, just for a consistency. FindAll could be slightly simpler in some cases, although that does limit you to having a `List<T>` as a source instead of only requiring `IEnumerale<T>`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
var match = carList.Where(x => x.id ==1 );
```